# python-xbrl installation error - ordereddict

Tags: python, windows, easy-install, xbrl

I try to install python-xbrl on Windows (Python 3.6.4) using easy_install.

However, I get the error that "Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse<"ordereddict">:

```
:\python-xbrl-master>easy_install python-xbrl
Searching for python-xbrl
Best match: python-xbrl 1.1.1
Processing python_xbrl-1.1.1-py3.6.egg
python-xbrl 1.1.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\python_xbrl-1.1.1-py3.6.egg
Processing dependencies for python-xbrl
Searching for ordereddict
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/ordereddict/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/ordereddict/: [Errno 11004] 
get addrinfo failed -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'ordereddict' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo 
failed -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or working download links found for ordereddict
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('ordereddict')
```

I have also tried with pip install python-xbrl, but I get:

```
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 
NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection
.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000004FBC240>: Failed to establish 
a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/marshmallow/
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement marshmallow (from 
python-xbrl) (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for 
marshmallow (from python-xbrl)
```

Can it be that my employer is blocking the network access?

Comment: Could you please right-click your terminal and choose "select" *(or just select the text)*, then right click to copy the text from your command terminal. That would greatly increase the risk of search engines being able to index the words in your picture. Also, if I'm not mistaken, `pip install python-xhrl` is usually how you would do it? Not that it might solve the issue in your case, but you should probably switch to it. It appears you have some network issues as well?

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I have tried with pip install but indeed it seems I have network problems - probably my employer is blocking the access?

Comment: Try `pip install -U marshmallow --pre`, then try `pip install python-xbrl` again.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Unfortunately the solution provided by Torxed also did not work - it failed to establish network connection - similar message with the one when trying to install with pip install python-xbrl.

Comment: Sounds like you have a network issue. Do you have a proxy between you and the internet? Have you tried this in another internet connection, etc?

Comment: I have checked with the employer, it seems to be a firewall that prevents employees from installing packages. Sorry to bother the community on this issue.